# Declaration of an enumeration type in a package

Tags: package, vhdl

I prefer to declare an enumeration type in a package so that I can use it in multiple entities. Here is my simplified code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.ALL;
use work.polar_package;

entity Decoder is
    port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic
    );
end entity Decoder;

architecture behavioral of Decoder is
    signal state : polar_package.state_type;
begin
    top_modul : process (clk)
    begin
        if clk = '1' and clk'event then
            if reset = '1' then
                state <= p0;
            else

            end if;
        end if;
    end process top_modul;
end architecture behavioral;
```

And I have declared and defined "state_type" in package "polar_package" as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

package polar_package is
    type state_type is (p0 , p1 , p2);
end package polar_package;

package body polar_package is

end package body polar_package;
```

However, I see the below compilation error:
Unknown identifier "p0"

is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You have an unneeded use clauses making Synospsys packages STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED, STD_LOGIC_SIGNED as well as IEEE package NUMERIC_STD declarations visible. You use clause for polar_package only makes that name visible as the Travis Bassano indicates. The reserved word all prefix for that use clause also makes subprograms with anonymous parameters for predefined operators (e.g. "=") and operations implicitly declared immediately after the type declaration directly visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try:

state <= polar_package.p0;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This daemon is complaining about the terseness of your reply. You could demonstrate it's correctness by using the Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example given in the question as well as an explanation of the visibility issues. Teaching the problem and a solution are useful for future readers.

Comment: This proposal somehow solved the problem. But I'm still confused why the use of state_type values must be prefixed with the package name!

Answer (score 1):

Try including the entire package,

```
use work.polar_package.all;
```

Or, if you want to be more explicit, only including the type you need:

```
use work.polar_package.state_type;
```